# JavaScript: What should keyCode be replaced with?

Tags: javascript, keycode

this is the js code:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode === 191) {
        document.getElementById('search-input').focus()
    }
})
```

but in visual studio code says: **keyCode is deprecated.**
What should this code be replaced with? Is there any need to do this at all?

Comment: check MDN [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
and use
    if (e.code=== 191) {

Comment: Is that answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394937/keyboardevent-keycode-deprecated-what-does-this-mean-in-practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [event.keyCode alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250534/event-keycode-alternative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace it with `e.key === 'Enter'` for example or `e.code === 'Enter'`.
You can find more information about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.key`. It's way easier to use, and working in *every* browser:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key == '/') {
        document.getElementById('search-input').focus()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The MDN documentation states the following:

> You should avoid using this (keyCode) if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use KeyboardEvent.code, if it's implemented. Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it, so you'll have to be careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

If you need to support older browsers (like Internet Explorer) you may want to use feature detection to use the correct one.

```
if (event.code !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.key
}
else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyCode
}
```